# how to get text from text field

Tags: java, android

I wanted to make an app that would get the test score from the text field (id etxt1) and on a click of a button it would show the grade in the other text field (id etxt2).

marks 100-91 grade A.

marks  90-81 grade B.

marks  80-71 grade C.

and so on.

and how to use the ">=" thing.

Here's my code:

```
Button bt1;
EditText etxt1;
EditText etxt2;
char grade = 0;
int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activitywhatsyourgrade);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    etxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testscore);
    final int score = etxt1.getTextAlignment();
    etxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (score == 90){
                etxt2.setText("A1");
            }
            else if (score ==80){
                etxt2.setText("A2");
            }
        }
    }); 
}    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activitywhatsyourgrade, menu);
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). `getTextAlignment()` is not going to give you the text. You want `getText()`.

Comment: Let me know how my answer works for you. If you don't understand completely, I can try and be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong.

`final int score = etxt1.getTextAlignment();` is incorrect because:

1. You define it outside of the button listener, and as `final`, so it never changes depending on input.
2. `getTextAlignment()` is not the function you want to call.

Here's how to fix it:

- Get rid of that line of code all together. We'll replace that *in* the button listener.
- We'll use [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) method to get the text from the EditText. It won't be returned as a String, but instead an [`Editable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html), so we'll use the [`toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()) method on that to use it as a String.
- Once we have the String representation of the score, we'll parse that to an integer to check which range of grade it's between.

This code is just for your button listener. Just replace it with this. It's self explanatory, so I won't give any more explanation for it.

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String strScore = etxt1.getText().toString();

        int score = Integer.parseInt(strScore);

        if (score >= 91) {
            etxt2.setText("A");
        }
        else if (score >= 81) {
            etxt2.setText("B");
        }
        else if (score >= 81) {
            etxt2.setText("B");
        }
        else if (score >= 71) {
            etxt2.setText("C");
        }
        else if (score >= 61) {
            etxt2.setText("D");
        }
        else {
            etxt2.setText("F");
        }
    }
});
```

---

**This next section is just extra, you don't have to read this part if you're not completely understanding the code so far:**

You may run into a problem where if the field is left blank when the button is pressed, your app will crash. This is because you're trying to parse an empty string (which is `""`) to a numerical value, which obviously cannot be done. The same thing will happen if the field is just a negative sign or decimal point.

To fix that, you can just wrap the part of your code that is parsing the String to an integer in a try-catch block. This will catch an exception that will be thrown for the problem stated above. Like this:

Replace this line:

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(strScore);
```

With this:

```
int score = 0;
try {
    score = Integer.parseInt(strScore);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // This means NFE was thrown, so the field text cannot be parsed
    // to a numerical value. Just leave score = 0 as it was initialized
}
```

Or you can use an if-statement to test if the input is valid (this solution is worse because it only catches three cases when there could possibly be more, depending on the keyboard restrictions):

```
int score = 0;
// if the input is not blank, a negative sign or a decimal point
if (!(strScore.equals("") || strScore.equals("-") || strScore.equals(".")) {
    score = Integer.parseInt(strScore);
}
```

Comment: i was just wondering this code is for class 9 grades what if i wanted to swipe for class9 xml to class 10 xml. how on a clck of a button the xml for class 10 pops up . the codes for the both are same. the xml files also have the same data.

Comment: @user3856892 Oh okay so if you're having trouble with that, post a new question on this site and people can answer that question as well. As for this one, could you please accept my answer if it works for you? It is the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: have posted the question mike. looking forward for your easy-to-understandanswer.thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857091/how-to-merge-two-appsparts-in-adroid-java

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = etxt1.getText().toString();
etxt2.setText(a);
```

Comment: Very rarely is an answer that only has code better than one that has code and takes the time to explain it.

Comment: @Jerome His point was you should include explanation in your answers. At the moment it's being flagged as low quality. It's harder to gain reputation on code only answers.

Comment: @Scott I don't get why this would get flagged... The answer/code is sooooo self-explanatory... It's not like it's a huge chunk of code, which one need to wrap one's head around!

Comment: @Vallentin I am not saying the answer is right or wrong. I am only weighing in on this answer because it was in a review queue because it meets the low quality answers requirement. So I am merely enforcing the JsonAller's point that with a short explanation the answer would avoid being caught up in the low quality queue. Besides if you look at the other answers with content besides code they have votes. It's simply advice, take it or leave it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an amendment to [Mike Yaworski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24846361/2333021)

While this code is correct that he gave...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String strScore = etxt1.getText().toString();

    int score = Integer.parseInt(strScore);

    ...
```

... there is a fundamental flaw in that `getText()` can and will return `null` if the field is left blank. That is because it is not returning a `String` - it is returning an `Editable`; hence why you have to call `toString()` on it.

Here is my correction to it. Note, I had to get the text from 2 items in the GUI, so I separated the logic into a `private` method that returned the given `String`

```
// Returns a String from and Editable. Deals with the null value
private String extractStringNumber(Editable text) { 
    if (text == null) return "0"; // Change this to fit you needs
    return text.toString();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String strScore = extractStringNumber(etxt1.getText());

    int score = Integer.parseInt(strScore); // This is now guaranteed not to fail as long as strScore can be represented as a number.
```

Comment: I agree that this should be done in case of a field being left blank, however that wasn't the question and I didn't want to daunt the questioner. I don't want to give him more than he can handle (after all, he doesn't know how to use >= lol). Also, this isn't an answer (as you stated, it's an amendment). Instead of leaving this as an answer, would you prefer that I add this to the bottom of my answer, giving you credit? Up to you, but this is just incomplete in itself.

Comment: You can if you want. I do provide the main gist of your answer in mine which is simple and answers the asker's question. Also, I think he does know how to use `>=`. I know when I was learning about displaying grades with the `if-else` structure, the `>=` was a little confusing until you actually followed the code step-by-step.

Comment: I did decide to simplify my code to be more inline with the asker's code.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is wrong. The Editable returned is not null when there is a blank field, and therefore your method `extractStringNumber` will not work. I tried it.

Comment: I added my own solution for the blank field problem to my answer. I hope this doesn't daunt him, but thanks (and not thanks lol) for bringing this common problem up.